# ssh without time

Tags: ssh, time

I have a device that doesn't have standard clock. each time its turned on the clock is set to 00:00 but progresses normally (e.g. 90 mins after startup it will be 01:30).
Will ssh have a problem running on this device or it doesn't matter? (time seems important in encryption)

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't matter - it would certainly not be an issue on a generic Linux-based system, apart from the timestamps in logs etc. not being accurate.

If this particular system doesn't like the lack of current time it may fare better if you use ***ssh key authentication*** - if supported - I haven't posted any links and I don't know what would be appropriate for your setup but a Web search will returns lots of info. Out of interest, what's the system?

Edit: Does your system support the NTP time deamon or command? If so you could have it set its clock to the correct time at startup.

Comment: I don't know what it supports... it can't even make a client mode socket, it can't connect to dhcp and whatnot.

Comment: What is this beast?

Comment: Some kind of minimized busybox, has only 128 mb of storage.